# jquery find links in block of text

Tags: jquery

I'm using this to return the links in text.

```
$links = $('.sceneText').find( "a" ).attr('href');
console.log($links);
```

It finds the first one, but none afterwards. There are 3 in this block of text. Any idea how I make it find all the links in some text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an array of `href`s:

```
var hrefArray = $('.sceneText a').map(function(){
    // will generate an array of absolute URLs:
    return this.href;
}).get();
```

To retrieve just the content of the `href` attributes:

```
var hrefArray = $('.sceneText a').map(function(){
    // will get the text from the href attribute:
    return this.getAttribute('href');
}).get();
```

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have helped!

Comment: Oh, very nice... That will be useful for me, as well - !

Answer (score 2):

Throw an `each` in there -

```
$('.sceneText').find( "a" ).each(function() {  
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
}
```

However, that will only work if your DOM tree looks like this:

```
<div class="sceneText"> 
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
    <a></a> 
</div>
```

If you have a `.sceneText` around each `a`, i.e.:

Then, you need to do this:

```
$('.sceneText').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).find("a").attr("href"));

});
```

Or, if you play with your selectors, you can probably get away without using `find()` at all:

```
$('.sceneText > a').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr("href"));

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through them like this.

```
$links = $('.sceneText').find( "a" ).attr('href');

    for(var i = 0; i < $links.length; i++) {
        console.log($links.get(i));
    }
```